# Battery drain, even disconnected

Tags: battery

So, I have been having issues with the car starting of late. Battery died randomly, got RAC out said battery was fine just dead. Jumped it and all was OK for 2 weeks. Then awake to it dead again, then that's been the same every morning I go near it.
Disconnected the battery completely and brought it inside so I could keep an eye on it and test its charge and its reducing by .03 per hour.
Everything pointing to bad battery, but the battery itself is barely a year and half old. The car hasn't had the most use of late, could this have caused it even with battery age?
Already spent a small fortune on the car this month and just wanting opinions before rushing out and spending more on a new battery when there could be more to it. Thanks

Comment: If the battery is only a year and a half old it may still be under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

If a battery drains while unhooked, it is either a bad battery or there is dirt or moisture between the terminals. Mix some baking soda with water. Clean the top of the battery with it. Don't let it pool. Dry with paper towels. If it still drains unhooked after a recharge, have it tested and replace if necessary.